# Is there a way to solve the problem with connecting more than two windows without crashing the program in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Right now I'm working on the prototype of a interactive test for pupils. This prototype has 4 windows: 'welcome' window; 'question1'; 'question2' and 'results'. I use python 3.7; pyqt5 and Qt Designer. For the last couple of days I've been searching through a lot of information to find the way how to assemble a GUI which would consist out of many windows that are called one by one when certain buttons in the windows are pushed. I managed to find only a couple of examples but these programs do not go beyond 2 windows. And that's when I came across my problem.

(file 'welcome')

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from question1 import Ui_question1

class Ui_welcome(object):

    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_question1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        welcome.close()
        self.window.show()
.

        self.startTheTest.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
```

(file 'question1')

```
class Ui_question1(object):

    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_question2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        question1.close()
        self.window.show()
# ...


        self.nextQuestion.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
```

(file 'question2')

```
from results import Ui_results

class Ui_question2(object):

    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_results()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        question2.hide()
        self.window.show()
# ... 

        self.goToTheResults.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
```

I want the program to display 'welcome' window, then when the only button 'start the test' is pushed I want it to pass on to the first question which this program already does. But when I want to move on from 'question1' to 'question2' by pushing 'nextQuestion' this is when it crashes. It says 'question1' is not defined. When I start the program directly by runing the file 'question1' it does get to the 2nd question but when the 'goToTheResults' button is pushed it crashes again. In this case it says 'question2' is not defined.

Comment: Why is there no `__init__` anywhere?

Comment: @Guimoute Actually there is. I only added here the information that changed myself in the default file which I had created in Qt Designer. As a reference I followed the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRRpbDFnMHI
Can you help me out?

Comment: You could use a `QStackedWidget` to show your questions one by one.